# Excel convert and remove spaces

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a row of numbers that I need to sum.  When I try to sum I get zero (0) when I know there should be a value.  The numbers all have a (-) negative sign at the end and an extra space at the end.

How do I convert this to an actual number, remove the extra space to be able to sum up?  Do I need to remove the (-) negative sign at the end and move to the front?

Here's the data I'm working with.

[image]

Comment: Sum ignores text and currently that is what your numbers are.  So yes you will need to rearrange the text into a format that excel will recognize as a number and convert them to such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the sum without a helper column use this array formula:

```
=SUM(VALUE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-",A1:A6)),"-","")&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A6,"-","")))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

This will assume any that do not have `-` at the end are positive numbers and sum as such.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly.  The SumProduct worked as well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers have just `,` `.` `-` then all you need is:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))
```

Otherwise you need one `SUBSTITUTE(A1,"something","")` for every non digit character (except for `,` `.`), and then to wrap it all in `=VALUE(someformulas)`.

If you want to move the minus to the front (but check first if you do have a `-` to move) then add the following before all of the `SUBSTITUTE`subformulas:

`IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",A1)),"-","")&`

Final product should look something like this:

`=VALUE(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",A1)),"-","")&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"something",""))`

Comment: This removes the (-) sign at the end and removes the extra characters, but how do I add a the (-) sign on the front side of the number?  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `=VALUE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-",A1)),"-","")&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the clean and trim functions keep everything as a text, and you have to convert the output of those functions back to a numeric for adding (done by adding 0 to the results of the Len and Trim functions).  Here is an array formula that will convert the formula the text and sum it up:

```
=SUM(TRIM(LEFT(A1:A6,LEN(A1:A6)-2))+0)
```

This assumes that your data is in cells A1:A6 and in the format you provided in your post.  Remember, it's an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, and not just enter (if done right, you'll see the curly brackets around the formula...I don't know how to do the fancy icons that people do on stackoverflow).

I wasn't sure if the negative was part of the number, or just a legacy of the source data.  If you want to keep the negative part, you can do something like this as well:

```
=SUM(TRIM(LEFT(A1:A6,LEN(A1:A6)-2))*-1)
```

Again, it's an array formula.

Comment: @pnuts oh no...I meant the Ctrl+Alt+Enter "boxes" that I see on array formula examples.  I'll see if I can find an example...

Answer (score 1):

Select the relevant Column, Text to Columns, Delimited by 'space', check Trailing minus for negative numbers.

Comment: Well I have learned my one thing today, time to go home.  Can't overwork the brain cells too much.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution assuming that all negative numbers will have `-` followed by  (a space) at the end. Use the following formula:

```
=SUM(VALUE(IF(RIGHT(A1:A6,2)="- ","-"&LEFT(A1:A6,LEN(A1:A6)-2),A1:A6)))
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a Find & Replace for '- '.

Then use -SUM(....) to sum and switch to negative.

Comment: What if some of those numbers are positive?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following formula which will remove the `-` sign and any unwanted spaces. It will then convert it to a value so you can `SUM()`.

```
=CLEAN(TRIM(LEFT(D6,LEN(D6)-1)))
```

Change the range as needed.

Comment: @pnuts Hmmm. I must have put in the wrong formula. I meant to put `=NUMBERVALUE(CLEAN(TRIM(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))))`. Thanks for catching that. `TRIM()` is harmless. There could have been leading spaces.

Comment: @pnuts Yeah, I totally misread the question. And `VALUE()` would be the right function, as Scott uses.